# Mobile speech recognition in Kazakh

Tags: android, machine-learning, speech-recognition

I want to create a little mobile application for android based on speech recognition. Problem is that there is no such API, which have kazakh dictionary (I tried to find). So, I want to use API which can create own dictionary. Is there any API?

I am not familiar with machine learning, but I understand that I have to teach the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A speech recognition system requires a little bit more than a dictionary.
Sphinx is an open source system that you may want to take a look into, at least to understand how things work. Pocketsphinx is their version for mobile devices.

From their FAQ:

Q: How to add support for a new language

The process of building a new language model consists of the following steps:

- Data collection (you can collect audiobooks with text transcriptoin
  from project like librivox, transcribed podcasts, or setup web data
  collection. You can also try to contribute to Voxforge. You can start
  very quickly with just few hours of transcribed data.
- Data cleanup
- Model training
- Testing

https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/#q-how-to-add-support-for-a-new-language

Comment: And actually CMUSphinx already supports Kazakh https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Kazakh/

Answer (score 1):

You can download Kazakh model (including Kazakh dictionary) in [CMUSphinx downloads](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Kazakh/)